# Criar coluna categórica a partir de outra coluna usando listas

Tags: python, pandas

Olá, estou tentando criar uma nova coluna no pandas a partir de uma coluna existente. Essa coluna contém nome de partidos políticos. Na nova coluna eu quero classificar a ideologia do partido. Para isso criei 3 listas contendo a orientação. Mas não estou conseguindo aplicar isso no pandas. Minha nova coluna deve retornar uma string com a orientação do partido: 'esquerda', ' centro', 'direita'.

```
esquerda = ['PSOL', 'PT', 'REDE', 'PCdoB', 'PSB', 'PV', 'PDT']
centro = ['SOLIDARIEDADE', 'CIDADANIA', 'AVANTE', 'PSD', 'PROS', 'MDB', 'PSDB', 'PODE']
direita = ['REPUBLICANOS', 'PP', 'PTB', 'UNIÃO', 'PATRIOTA', 'PSC', 'PL', 'NOVO']

# dentre algumas formas eu tentei esse método, mas 
# retorna erro
df_3['ideologia'] = np.where(df_3['partido'] in esquerda, 'esquerda', \
                         df_3['partido'] in centro, 'centro', \
                        df_3['partido'] in direita, 'direita')
```

Me retorna esse erro: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Meu dataframe tem essa cara aqui: (não sei bem como representar ele na postagem)

```
    nome              estado        partido 
0   abou anni         São Paulo     UNIÃO   
1   acacio favacho    Amapá         MDB 
2   adolfo viana      Bahia         PSDB    
3   adriana ventura   São Paulo     NOVO    
4   adriano do baldy  Goiás         PP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja uma forma de fazer isto utilizando a estrutura que você definiu anteriormente, porém ao invés de arrays de cada partido eu defino um dicionário que contém todos:

```py
partidos = {
  "esquerda": ['PSOL', 'PT', 'REDE', 'PCdoB', 'PSB', 'PV', 'PDT'],
  "centro": ['SOLIDARIEDADE', 'CIDADANIA', 'AVANTE', 'PSD', 'PROS', 'MDB', 'PSDB', 'PODE'],
  "direita": ['REPUBLICANOS', 'PP', 'PTB', 'UNIÃO', 'PATRIOTA', 'PSC', 'PL', 'NOVO']
}

def defineIdeologia(partido):
  for k in partidos:
    if partido in partidos[k]:
      return k

df_3["ideologia"] = df_3["partido"].apply(defineIdeologia)
```

Answer (score 0):

consegui resolver o problema criando listas e iterando.

```
b = list(df_3['partido'])
ideologia = []
for x in b:
    if x in esquerda:
        #print('esquerda')
        ideologia.append('esquerda')
    elif x in direita:
        #print('direita')
        ideologia.append('direita')
    else:
        ideologia.append('centro')

df_3['ideologia'] = ideologia
```

Mas gostaria de saber se tem algum modo mais simples para fazer isso. Obrigado